# DBSQL_SQL_INTERNAL_DB_ERROR SQL error 2048

Tags: abap, hana, opensql

I have to join two tabled ACDOCA and BKPF. I have written the follow code for it.

```
SELECT  a~rbukrs,
        a~racct,
        a~bldat,
        a~blart,
        a~kunnr,
        a~belnr,
        a~sgtxt,
        b~xblnr,
        a~budat,
        a~hsl,
        a~prctr
INTO TABLE @it_final
FROM acdoca AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bkpf AS b
  ON a~rbukrs = b~bukrs
 AND a~gjahr = b~gjahr
WHERE a~rbukrs IN @s_bukrs
  AND a~Kunnr IN @s_kunnr
  AND a~Budat IN @s_budat
  AND a~Belnr IN @s_belnr
  AND a~rldnr IN @s_rldnr
  AND a~blart = 'DR' OR a~blart = 'ZK' OR a~blart = 'UE'.
```

Facing the following errors:----
Runtime error: DBSQL_SQL_INTERNAL_DB_ERROR

SQL error "SQL code: 2048" occurred while accessing table "ACDOCA".

Short Text: An exception has occurred in class "CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB"

How do I resolve this? please help.

Comment: not addressing the problem but your where clause is highly suspect with the "OR's" on a~blart written that way.  You probabably want `AND a~blart in ('DR,'ZK','UE')` or...`AND (a~blart = 'DR' OR a~blart = 'ZK' OR a~blart = 'UE')  or your other and criteria will get associated only to the first a~blart and you'll get back all ZK and UE a~blart records.

Comment: 2nd... I'm not familiar  with `alias~field` notation.  Isn't it usually `alias.fieldname` or is this an ABAP thing which I know almost nothing about.

Comment: going back to first comment 2048 is a Memory Allocation failed error.  It may simply be your "OR" clauses are returning too much data.  Try limiting the data to a few records see if it works.  If it does; it's likely too much data and you're either missing join critiera from acdoca to bkpf or the "OR's" are returning much more than you expect.

Comment: @xQbert yes, that's ABAP syntax. The dot is used in ABAP to end a statement.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to write your own query or is there a CDS view that already performs this JOIN?

Comment: Also for context: ACDOCA is a very large table, sometimes having billions of entries. Be very careful that the query always limits the result set or things will blow up :)

Comment: The JOIN condition has to include the belnr as well: a~belnr = b~belnr

Comment: You might be interested in [SAP Help: CDS Views](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8308e6d301d54584a33cd04a9861bc52/2021.000/en-US/5418de55938d1d22e10000000a44147b.html) to find a fitting view for your usecase

Comment: Please add the relevant tag to indicate your database system. I assume it's HANA (based on the code 2048).

Comment: In HANA, not sure what database you are talking about, the code 2048 is a generic error for "column store error". The case "memory allocation error" is just one possibility. For more information, see note [2399990 - How-To: Analyzing ABAP Short Dumps in SAP HANA Environments](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2399990)

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- Selecting directly from the database tables is error prone (e.g. you'll forget keys while joining) and you have to deal with those terrible german abbreviations (e.g. Belegnummer -> belnr). Since quite some time there are CDS Views on top such as [`I_JournalEntryItem`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8308e6d301d54584a33cd04a9861bc52/2021.000/en-US/47dce95760521070e10000000a44147b.html) with associations and proper english names for those fields, if you can use them, I would (also they're [C1 released](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8308e6d301d54584a33cd04a9861bc52/2021.000/en-US/2e4edbede2f94fb7b7f6eac856c02b19.html)).
- As already pointed out by xQBert the query does probably not work as intended as AND has prescendence over OR, and as such your query basically returns *everything from ACDOCA, multiplied by everything from BKPF* which likely leads to the database error you've posted
- With range queries you might still get a *lot of results* (like billions of entries, depending on your company's size), you should either limit the query with `UP TO`, implement some pagination or `COUNT(*)` first and show an error to the user if the result set is too large.

I would write that like this:

```
TYPES:
 BEGIN OF t_filters,
  company_codes TYPE RANGE OF bukrs,
  customers     TYPE RANGE OF kunnr,
  document_dates TYPE RANGE OF budat,
  accounting_documents TYPE RANGE OF fis_belnr,
  ledgers TYPE RANGE OF rldnr,
 END OF t_filters.

DATA(filters) = VALUE t_filters(
  " filter here
).

SELECT FROM I_JournalEntryItem
  FIELDS
    CompanyCode,
    GLAccount,
    DocumentDate,
    AccountingDocumentType,
    Customer,
    AccountingDocument,
    DocumentItemText,
    \_JournalEntry-DocumentReferenceID,
    PostingDate,
    AmountInCompanyCodeCurrency,
    ProfitCenter
  WHERE
    CompanyCode            IN @filters-company_codes AND
    Customer               IN @filters-customers AND
    DocumentDate           IN @filters-document_dates AND
    AccountingDocument     IN @filters-accounting_documents AND
    Ledger                 IN @filters-ledgers AND
    AccountingDocumentType IN ( 'DR', 'ZK', 'UE' )
  INTO TABLE @DATA(sales_orders)
  UP TO 100 ROWS.
```

(As a bonus you'll get proper DCL authorization checks)

Answer (score 2):

2048 is/can be a memory allocation error:  Too much data being returned.  Given that, this line is highly suspect

```
  AND a~blart = 'DR' OR a~blart = 'ZK' OR a~blart = 'UE'.
```

I'd consider this instead.  Otherwise ALL blart ZK and UE records are returned regardless of customer, year, company et...

```
SELECT  a~rbukrs,
        a~racct,
        a~bldat,
        a~blart,
        a~kunnr,
        a~belnr,
        a~sgtxt,
        b~xblnr,
        a~budat,
        a~hsl,
        a~prctr
INTO TABLE @it_final
FROM acdoca AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bkpf AS b
  ON a~rbukrs = b~bukrs
 AND a~gjahr = b~gjahr
WHERE a~rbukrs IN @s_bukrs
  AND a~Kunnr IN @s_kunnr
  AND a~Budat IN @s_budat
  AND a~Belnr IN @s_belnr
  AND a~rldnr IN @s_rldnr
  AND a~blart IN ('DR','ZK','UE').
```

However, if you really did mean to return all blart ZK, UE records  and only those that ar DR and in the defined parameters... you're simply asking for too much data from teh system and need to "LIMIT" your result set and somehow let the user know only a limited set is being returned due to data volume

I'd also ensure your join on keys is sufficient.  Fiscal Year and company code represent an incomplete key to BKPF.  I dont' know ACDOCA data table so I'm unsure if that's a proper join which may be leading to a semi-cartesean contributing to data bloat.    I'd think in a multi-tenant db, you may need to join on mandt as well... possibly a doc number and some other values... again, this lookst to be an incomplete join on key.... so perhaps more is needed there as well.

Comment: When you do have a case where you need to query very large amounts of data which don't fit into memory at once, then the statement OPEN CURSOR might help to process the data in chunks.

Comment: In HANA, not sure what database the OP is talking about, the code 2048 is a generic error for "column store error". The case "memory allocation error" is just one possibility. For more information, see note [2399990 - How-To: Analyzing ABAP Short Dumps in SAP HANA Environments](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2399990)

Comment: @SandraRossi  Sorry, I see it sooooooooo much I'm just use to refering to 2048 as a memory error. 99/100 times where I work with it; it's that.

Comment: @SandraRossi OP is selecting from table acdoca, so this must be a HANA DB

Comment: So SAP ERP system can't run on oracle?   I mean can't a table of that name exist on any RDBMS? (shrug)

Comment: The `ACDOCA` table is one of the tables specifically designed for S/HANA. This version of the SAP ERP system runs exclusively on HANA.

Comment: `AND (a~blart IN ('DR','ZK','UE'))` outer parentheses are redundant here, `IN` is a single [logical expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_list.htm) here